# Instance of Bean in Singleton scope in Spring

Tags: spring, javabeans

I've created some classes to test scope of Bean in Spring as below
In my understand, if the scope is singelton then Spring always gives only one instance for helloWorld object. It means when I run the program then the output will be

Your Message : Hello from Nam Tran
Alert from TestBeanScope:
Your Message : Hello from Nam Tran

But actually, the output is :

Your Message : Hello from Nam Tran
Alert from TestBeanScope:
Your Message : Hello World!

Could you please explain why?

===

```
package namtran.tutorial;

public class HelloWorld {
       private String message;

       public void setMessage(String message){
          this.message  = message;
       }
       public void getMessage(){
          System.out.println("Your Message : " + message);
       }
    }
```

==========

```
package namtran.tutorial;

import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class TestBeanScope {
    public void getMessage(){
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        AbstractApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");
        HelloWorld obj = (HelloWorld) context.getBean("helloWorld");
         System.out.println("Alert from TestBeanScope:\n");
        obj.getMessage();
    }
}
```

=============

```
package namtran.tutorial;

import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class MainApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      @SuppressWarnings("resource")
      AbstractApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");

      HelloWorld obj = (HelloWorld) context.getBean("helloWorld");
      obj.setMessage("Hello from Nam Tran");
      obj.getMessage();

      context.registerShutdownHook();
      TestBeanScope obj1 = new TestBeanScope();
      obj1.getMessage();

    }
}
```

====Beans.xml====

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

  <bean id="helloWorld" 
       class="namtran.tutorial.HelloWorld" scope="singleton">
       <property name="message" value="Hello World!"/>
   </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, follow the [ClassPathXmlApplicationContext doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.html)

> In case of multiple config locations, later bean definitions will override ones defined in earlier loaded files

When you first create a context in your main method and set the `message`, it will print
`Your Message : Hello from Nam Tran`
Then you created new context in `TestBeanScope` so that `helloWorld` bean will be overiden. Its message will be `Hello World!` as it was declared in `Beans.xml`. Therefore, the message is
`Alert from TestBeanScope: Hello World!`

Comment: How can I do if I want the output is "Your Message : Hello from Nam Tran". It means I have to pass the context object to TestBeanScope class, this way is not my expectation for keep an instance of the bean

Comment: You can inject ApplicationContext using annotation `@Autowired` or implement interface [ApplicationContextAware](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextAware.html)

Comment: I mean I'd like to find a feature that bean can be gotten everywhere. Inject ApplicationContext is not my way. You imagine session scope for the bean with web application. It's really way I want.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. You can inject any bean by declaring it and put annotation `@Autowired` above it.

Comment: I mean the bean will be cached somewhere. Even you init new ApplicationContext then the cached bean will be fetched, so the instance is the same. How can we ignore @autowire

Comment: This is beyond the scope of my knowledge but I don't know why you have to instance more than one context with the same configuration xml file.